# Can I run R scripts in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is it possible to call an R script from an AWS Glue job? I would need to pass parameters to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to run R on AWS Glue. Python is officially supported, but the following quote from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-custom-created.html) suggests that it may be possible using something like [SparkR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) in the future:

> Your custom script must be compatible with Apache Spark 2.1.